# XML Schema: how to reference a type from a no namespace XSD

Tags: xml, import, xsd, namespaces, wsdl

So I have an XSD that has no namespace specified.

I then import it into another schema (B.xsd) that has namespace specified with "targetnamespace='my-name-space'"

```
<import schemalocation="A.xsd"/>
```

After that I want to create an element in B.xsd

```
<element name="AuthenticationRequest" type="AuthenticationRequest"/>
```

This fails the validation saying that type AuthenticationRequest are no found.
This type is actually defined in A.xsd.

How do I reference this type from A.xsd in B.xsd??

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that the `type` attribute is a QName, meaning that it is sensitive to prefix bindings.

If the imported schema has no namespace, which seems to be the case here, then the value of the `type` attribute should be unprefixed. However, since in the schema snippet it seems that the default namespace is defined and identical to the XML Schema namespace (`http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`), the engine attempts looking up a type called `AuthenticationRequest` in the XML Schema namespace. This can be solved by binding the XML Schema namespace to a prefix, often `xs` or `xsd`, rather than making it default.

```
<xs:schema
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  ...
>
    <xs:import schemalocation="A.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="AuthenticationRequest" type="AuthenticationRequest"/>
</xs:schema>
```

For completeness: if the imported schema has a target namespace, two things need to be done:

1. Binding the target namespace of the imported schema to some prefix, say, `imported`
2. Prefixing the value of the `type` attribute with this prefix, like so:

   ```
   <xs:schema
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:imported="http://www.example.com/imported"
     ...
   >
     <xs:import schemalocation="A.xsd" namespace="http://www.example.com/imported"/>
     <xs:element name="AuthenticationRequest" type="imported:AuthenticationRequest"/>
   </xs:schema>
   ```

As mentioned in the link posted on chameleon design, an alternative to *importing* a schema is *including* a schema.

However, even with this design, the value of the `type` attribute still needs to be defined properly, that is:

- either with no prefix (and no default namespace) if there is no target namespace
- or with the appropriate prefix, bound to the target namespace
- or with no prefix, with the target namespace being defined as the default namespace

Very importantly, the above applies even if there is only one schema, with no other schemas imported or included. It works out of the box if the schema has no namespace, but it needs to be considered if there is a target namespace.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I often get confused with the namespace when there are a lot of namespaces and bindings going on. Especially when an WSDL has many XSD imports and they're not in the same namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out after spending time reading online.
I read about "chameleon" design and it helps me understand more about namespace.

http://www.xfront.com/ZeroOneOrManyNamespaces.html